# BundleException by Apache Karaf 4.2.6 with Java 12

Tags: apache-karaf, java-12

Apache Karaf 4.2.6 launched with JDK 11 or 12 throws an exception while starting and stop. I need at least JDK 11 because I have an application written in JDK 11 using the `Websocket` class available since JDK 11.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:876)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:215)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:256)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:178)
```

Comment: Hi quaddan, welcome to StackOverflow.  What makes you think that this error is Java 11/12 specific? This is an OSGi exception complaining about an empty export. Did you maybe create a faulty bundle information?

Comment: Hi Nicolai. Because setting the JDK to 1.8 solve the problem.
Detailled message is:
Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url: mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.extension/4.2.6 and startlevel: 1.
For information, it's a fresh installation without any modification. But starting Karaf with: sudo ./karaf thwos this Exception
No problem with JDK 1.8.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KARAF/issues/KARAF-6203 AFAIK jdk11 only supported

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Must wait for Karaf 4.3.0.